# BBM integrated with App

Tags: blackberry, bb-messenger

I am developing an app where I need to use BlackBerry Messenger (BBM) in it. As I am new to Blackberry development I don't know how to do it. Actually I have gone through many sites & I came to know that I need to install BBM SDK ... after that I get problem not find class error .. I solved this by verifying the jar and used the generated one, but I still have the problem that I get the error and can't build the project .. So I need to know how to integrate BBM into my App? 
As I am new to this development any small help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2):

This is the official page:
http://us.blackberry.com/sites/developers/blackberry-messenger.html

Also have a look at the TicTacToe sample project inside JDE.